# OAuth2 iOS, access token and refresh token automatically renewal

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, afnetworking-2

I am trying to implement OAuth2 for an iOS app and I am currently using this extension for AFNetworking : https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFOAuth2Manager, but it doesn't renew automatically the access and refresh token. Can you tell me, please, what should I use?